# UIViews SetNeedsDisplay not called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, setneedsdisplay

Newbie Alert! : ) There are multiple views in my app, all set up in the story board and all having their own subclassed UIView classes with their own overwritten drawRect-methods. One of them works as a button and is able to redraw itself via setneedsdisplay and calls a function of another UIViews class:

```
import UIKit

class Button: UIView {
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    let touchPoint: CGPoint! = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
    if butouched == true{
        if touchPoint.x > bounds.size.width - bounds.size.height && touchPoint.x < bounds.size.width && touchPoint.y > 0 && touchPoint.y < bounds.size.height{
            counter++
            setNeedsDisplay()  //thats the setNeedsDisplay that works
            DrawGraph().updateModell()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the setNeedsDisplay in this function didn't work, even though the updateModell-function is called:

```
import UIKit

class DrawGraph: UIView {
func updateModell() {
    setNeedsDisplay() // thats the setNeedsDisplay that doesn't work
}
```

So I googled and googled but just can't figure out whats wrong. And yes, this is my first week with Swift and iOS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outlet for between your View on Storyboard and DrawGraph, suppose you name it DrawGraphV, be sure that view is Custom class DrawGraph, you don't need the method updateModell, just call directly DrawGraphV.SetNeedsDisplay

Comment: Although the core of your answer is correct, it is vague for somebody as the OP unfamiliar with the programming language, please include a code example if possible to make your answer more clear.

Comment: Hey hey, the OP isn't that unfamiliar with the programming language ; ) not more

Answer (score 0):

Here's your call to `updateModell`:

```
DrawGraph().updateModell()
```

This line creates a **new instance** of `DrawGraph` and sends it the `updateModell` message. This new instance of `DrawGraph` is not in your view hierarchy. It is separate from any other instances of `DrawGraph`. Since nothing references this new instance of `DrawGraph`, this instance is deleted immediately after `updateModell` returns.  Do you understand now why this call to `updateModell` has no effect on the screen?

I don't know why you decided to try to implement your own `Button` class. Is there some reason you don't like `UIButton`?

The normal way to implement this would be to put the `counter` property in your view controller (or in a model object referenced by your view controller). The view controller also has references to the button and the existing `DrawGraph`. Connect the “Touches Ended” event of the button to an `IBAction` method in the view controller. In the `IBAction` method, update the counter, update the button's label (or whatever), and send `updateModell` to the existing instance of `DrawGraph`.

Comment: Thanks! What I particularly understand now is that I understand very little, I'm just a designer who was told programming isn't that hard ; )

Comment: But maybe you can tell me how to send updateModell to the existing instance of DrawGraph?

Comment: I can't tell you that because it's very specific to the way your application is written. It sounds like you need to work through more tutorials to learn the basic concepts of object-oriented programming and iOS programming.

Comment: Allright, sounds like my old learning by doing approach didn't work here as usual. Thanks.